# Java 8 and Spring 4 : Use autowiring in interface

Tags: java-8, spring-4

Java 8 added a new feature by which we can provide method implementation in interfaces.
Is there any way in Spring 4 by which we can inject beans in the interface which can be used inside the method body?
Below is the sample code

```
public interface TestWiring{

@Autowired
public Service service;// this is not possible as it would be static.
//Is there any way I can inject any service bean which can be used inside testWiringMethod.
default void testWiringMethod(){
  // Call method of service
  service.testService();
 }
}
```

Comment: You can't instantiate an interface. How would you autowire a field in it?

Comment: I want to use spring managed services inside my method body. One way is to use ApplicationContext.getbean("<bean-name">) method. But I am looking for any feature in Spring 4 which I can leverage for injecting Spring managed beans in interface. Interface would be implemented by some bean. So it should be available in the implementing class. By default since members of interface are static final so I can not use @autowiring directly.

Comment: DI in Spring works either by setting the dependencies in the constructor (constructor injection), or via property (setter injection). In an interface, you do not have a constructor, nor instance variables (the variables you declare in an interface are `static final`), so there is no way to inject anything.

Comment: Cant you use abstract class for this ?

Comment: A possible use case can be in Spring Data interfaces which implement CRUD Repository. I am testing the new Spring R2DBC with Mysql. So like usual Spring Data Interfaces, there is no way to write custom abstract methods like findByIdLike and other custom queries without providing the implementation. In this case, I need to use the Database client and write the custom method with the implementaton, maybe using the new Java 8 default methods. I don't want to write a new Interface and implementation class since both Spring and my interface would be interacting with the same Entity/Table.

Comment: in a default method you can provide code, so the question is perfectly posed

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is a bit tricky but it works if you need the dependency inside the interface for whatever requirement.

The idea would be to declare a method that will force the implemented class to provide that dependency you want to autowire.

The bad side of this approach is that if you want to provide too many dependencies the code won't be pretty since you will need one getter for each dependency.

```
public interface TestWiring {

   public Service getService();

   default void testWiringMethod(){
       getService().testService();
   }

}


public class TestClass implements TestWiring {

    @Autowire private Service service;

    @Override
    public Service getService() {
        return service;
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually I don't think this is a bad idea, since it shows clearly that the interface needs those fields.

Comment: 1+ For solution, But for these cases Abstract class is better option

Comment: But what service class is this? Is this "javax.xml.ws.Service"?

Answer (score 6):

You can created Class utils of application context and use it everywhere even not bean class .

you can have code somethins this :

```
@Component
    public class ApplicationContextUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {
        
            private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;
        
            @Override
            public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) {
                ApplicationContextUtil.applicationContext = context;
            }
        
            public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
                return applicationContext;
            }
}
```

now simple to use when you need :

```
ApplicationContextUtil.getApplicationContext().getBean(SampleBean.class)
```

this word in web and simple spring app.

Comment: What if you don't use xml? Can you simple use @Component?

Comment: @Please_Dont_Bully_Me_SO_Lords not diffrent just another way to declare bean

Comment: This is considered bad practice as it's hard to test

Comment: Also, you don't need the xml part. Just add the `@Service` annotation

Comment: For me, applicationContext use is for legacy Spring. No use in modern Spring, too low level API

Comment: Is a good way to update a static field from a non-static method.